How is Emergency Braking Assist implemented?
No, I am not talking about automatic braking assistance, which automatically applies the brakes without user input when obstacles are detected.
I’m talking about plain old brake assist.  In this 1997 press release  from Toyota, the then-new system is described:

Brake Assist interprets a quick push of the brake pedal as emergency
braking and supplements the braking power applied if the driver has
not stepped on the brake pedal hard enough.

I experienced this in a 2012 Prius, and it behaved basically as described: I jammed on the brakes suddenly, and I felt the car apply a brake response that was disproportionately larger than the position of the brake pedal would normally call for.
I noticed this feature is standard on the 2015 Toyota Yaris, which surprised me because usually you don’t see “premium features” like brake assist on econoboxes.
I have serviced brake systems in economy cars (usually with a disks-in-the-front, drums-in-the-back setup).  My understanding was that the brakes are a hydraulic system, assisted by the brake booster.  The driver pushes the pedal, which compresses the master cylinder, which creates pressure in the brake lines, causing the brake fluid to actuate the pistons and drums, with extra assistance from the brake booster.
So how is this feature actually implemented?  Presumably, the car has a brake pedal input sensor to detect sudden inputs.  But how does the car “take control” and actuate the brake system to apply full braking force?
Remember, I’m not talking about a fancy drive-by-wire car.  A simple car like a 2015 Yaris, as far as I know, doesn’t have brake by wire, and instead has the conventional system that I described above.  Besides, I don’t think brake by wire really existed in 1997 when this feature was apparently introduced by Toyota.  So how do they do it? Isn’t the physical brake pedal the only real input to this system?

This may help as M-B introduced braking assist in the 90s, too; https://auto.howstuffworks.com/car-driving-safety/safety-regulatory-devices/brake-assist.htm. Many manufacturers have incorporated brake assist in their cars. More info can reveal components used in each vehicle.

If your car has ABS, then no the physical brake pedal is not the only input to the system, and the electronics which control the ABS actuator can do the job you describe.

Traction control too. Some (all?) traction control systems use the ABS system to apply light braking to a wheel that is spinning faster than the vehicle speed because it has lost traction. When that happens, your foot is on the accelerator, not on the brake pedal.

Brake assist systems (BAS) have been implemented based on conventional hydraulic brakes since the 1990s. At around year 2000, there were 3 BAS variants. I don't know which variant was used by Toyota at that time.
Electronically controlled I (hydraulic)
In hydraulic brake assist systems, the return flow pump of the anti-lock braking system provides extra pressure. Emergency situations are detected by an electronic control unit which monitors the pressure development gradient using a pressure sensor. If the gradient indicates that the brake is applied fast and with high force, BAS intervention is triggered.
When triggered, switch valves, which also play a role in ABS/ESP, are activated to direct pressure from the return flow pump to the wheel brake cylinders. The system increases brake pressure to a maximum until ABS kicks in.
Electronically controlled II (pneumatic)
Emergency situations are detected by an electronic control unit which monitors how fast the brake is applied using a sensor linked to the brake servo membrane. If the value is over a threshold coded into the control unit, BAS intervention is commanded.
When BAS intervention is commanded, a solenoid valve in the servo opens to cause an almost instant increase in (pneumatic) pressure. The servo boosts the brake force as strong as if the driver would press the brake pedal a lot harder.
The "extra force" comes from the regular brake servo.
Mechanical
In a mechanical brake assist system, emergency situations are detected by a mechanical switch component in the brake servo. This component contains an elastic element which deforms more the harder and faster the brake pedal is pushed. When the disc deforms enough the switch component locks. This is the mechanical equivalent of the electronic control unit.
When the switch component locks, a spring is "activated" which takes up a portion of the counter-force coming from the brakes. This force can no longer felt in the brake pedal. The driver has to overcome a smaller force to brake more heavily.
